# How to set onclick to parent working more than once?

Tags: javascript

I have this example code:

```html
<script>
    function opendiv(obj){
        obj.innerHTML = '   <form> \
        <input type="text" placeholder="Id" name="id"/> \
        <input type="button" name="Go" onclick="closediv(this,event);"/> \
    </form>';
        obj.className = "b";
        obj.onclick = '';
    }
    
    function closediv(obj){
        obj = obj.parentElement.parentElement;
        obj.className = "a";
        obj.onclick = 'open(this);';
        obj.innerHTML = 'open';
        event.stopPropagation();

    }
</script>
<div class="a" onclick="opendiv(this);">open
</div>
```

The problem is that first click on `opendiv` works.
Also click on `closediv` works.
Another click to restored `opendiv` not working.

Answer (score 1):

When you have to pass a value by assigning it to onclick you need to assign an anonymous function

```
obj.onclick = function() {opendiv(this)};
```

With *parenthesis* it will not work

```
obj.onclick = opendiv(this); // this doesn't work
```

```html
<script>
    function opendiv(obj){
    console.log("HERE");
        obj.innerHTML = '   <form> \
        <input type="text" placeholder="Id" name="id"/> \
        <input type="button" name="Go" onclick="closediv(this,event);"/> \
    </form>';
        obj.className = "b";
        obj.onclick = '';
    }
    
    function closediv(obj){
        obj = obj.parentElement.parentElement;
        console.log(obj);
        obj.className = "a";
        obj.onclick = function(){opendiv(this)};
        obj.innerHTML = 'open';
        
        event.stopPropagation();

    }
</script>
<div class="a" onclick="opendiv(this);">open
</div>
```

Comment: Tahnk you so much @Alex it works!!
I don't understand because apparently same method obj.onclick not working but it's wonderful to had a solution.

Comment: You're welcome :) @Kosmos3D
I have explained it in my solution

Answer (score 0):

You might consider

- Including your form directly in your HTML (initially hidden with a CSS selector like ".hidden"), and/or
- Using [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline event handlers.

The main benefits of these changes would be cleaner code and better separation of concerns on your page (i.e. Markup vs Styling vs Scripting). Additionally, including HTML directly can be less error-prone than inserting it dynamically, and event listeners provide more versatility than inline event handlers.

---

This example uses a CSS selector called `.hidden` to **show/hide either the form itself or the "open form" button**, depending on what the user clicks.

(Note that because you're using a form element, hitting Enter while the `input` element has the focus will trigger a "submit" event, which navigates the browser away from our page.)

```js
// Identifies DOM elements
const
  container = document.getElementById("container"),
  openButton = document.getElementById("open-button"),
  idForm = document.getElementById("id-form");

// Calls `toggleForm` when the user clicks in the container div
container.addEventListener("click", toggleForm);

// Defines the event listener function
function toggleForm(event){ // Listener has access to triggering event
  const btn = event.target; // Event has useful properties like .target
  if(!btn.classList.contains("toggle-form")){ // Ignores irrelevant clicks
    return;
  }
  if(btn.classList.contains("open")){
    // Shows form and hides "open" button
    idForm.classList.remove("hidden");
    openButton.classList.add("hidden");
  }
  else if(btn.classList.contains("close")){
    // Hides form and shows "open" button
    idForm.classList.add("hidden");
    openButton.classList.remove("hidden");
  }
  else{
    // In case the page has any other".toggle-form" elements
    console.log("This will never happen");
  }
}
```

```css
/* Lets CSS handle what the user sees */
.hidden{ display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!-- Elements with "toggle-form" class are special to our listner -->
  <button id="open-button" class="toggle-form open">OPEN FORM</button>
  <!-- When page loads, form already has "hidden" class -->
  <form id="id-form" class="hidden">
    <label>Id<input name="id"/></label>
    <input type="button" class="toggle-form close" name="Go"/>
  </form>
</div>
```